# Git init doesn't create master branch

Tags: git

I seem to have a problem with the git not initializing the master branch when creating a new local repository. When I run "git init", the master branch doesn't seem to be created. Here's the copy-paste from my command line

```
C:\Users\KJA\workspace\gitproblem>git init
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/KJA/workspace/gitproblem/.git/

C:\Users\KJA\workspace\gitproblem>git branch

C:\Users\KJA\workspace\gitproblem>git branch mybranch
fatal: Not a valid object name: 'master'.

C:\Users\KJA\workspace\gitproblem>
```

Is there a bug in the newest version of git for windows or something?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Git init creates a repo without any commits.

Since a branch is a pointer to a commit, you can't have branches until you commit something.

Comment: well... that was fast :D I didn't know it, but it looks like you were right :)

Comment: Agreed. Maybe you can check this link http://classic.scottr.org/presentations/git-in-5-minutes/  for more info on how to set up your repository locally

Comment: Weird that `git status` on a newly created repo (via `git init`) says "On branch master" when `git branch` says that there are no branches.